# How to search names that have accent without using accent?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Example, I have a user in my database named **Rosé Brat**

I would like my users to be able to search **Rosé** by typing *Rose* only, without the accent **é**. How is that possible using MySQL, I'm currently using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%$search_query%'
```

which does not search for Rosé when typed Rose.

Column **name** is VARCHAR (60) utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: `é` is not a tilde. It is an *accented e*. Symbols like `´` are generally called *diacritics*.

`~` is a tilde.

Comment: What column type and character set is `name`?

Comment: @GeorgeBahij Oops sorry! Thanks!

Comment: @MarcusAdams Varchar (60)

Comment: @MarcusAdams - Do you mean `collation`?

Comment: @MarcusAdams utf8_unicode_ci

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these methods:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%$search_query%' collate utf8_general_ci
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE _utf8'%$search_query%' collate utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: Which one do I use? There's 2

Comment: the first one assumes your column  set to utf8 like `set names utf8`,  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html if not then use second one

Comment: The collation for "name" field is utf8_unicode_ci. Will it still work? Or do I have to change it to utf8_general_ci?

Answer (score -1):

You need to look at SOUNDEX().

Try something like

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE soundex(name) = soundex(''%$search_query%');
```

SOUNDEX takes the letters/syllables in a word and encodes them in such a way that words sounding similar will have similar encoded values. You'll need to play around with it to see what it does for you with likely search terms, but that is probably the easiest way to go.

[Examples here.](http://www.madirish.net/?article=85)

Comment: @TrondroMulligan - I didn't image it was you. I've got no way of finding out who it was (and don't really care). I was just wondering why. It may not be the best andswer, but it is an answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could consider soundex, although it may pull "rosy" "rosie" and "rosee" as well.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex

Maybe something like:

```
select * from users where soundex(name) =  soundex('%$search_query%') ;
```

Probably want to make sure you are using proper php bindings to avoid any sql injection as well.

Other than that the only thing that comes to mind is potentially using some regex or translation to replace characters which could get messy.

Comment: with a downvote could you please provide a comment as to why?